# Exchange 2003 OWA one user cannot view invites

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

Environment: Single exchange 2003 box, running on server 2k3.  latest service packs applied.  all but latest round of patches applied.

Symptom: A single user cannot view any meeting invite via IMAP/OWA.  Works fine in outlook, but its a users who primarily uses linux, so thats not an option.  They get HTTP 500 responses for every calendar invite they have.  Tried in Firefox/Chrome/IE (7 on xp). This isnt new, its just being reported for the first time.

Nobody else is reporting the issue.

Ive certainly seen this here and there with corrupt invites, but not every invite in a mailbox.

Edit 2 (more detail): Its actually just updates & cancellations the error is occurring on.  Also, updates and cancellations do not appear when the user connects via IMAP.

Comment: OWA is known to not work so well with non-IE browsers. Maybe your user could try a different browser in his Linux environment?

Comment: updated writeup to reflect this - that was one of the first things i had him try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following registry entry solved the issue:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeIS\ParametersSystem\InternetContent\MimeHandlers{85D2DDB8-6225-11D2-BDF1-00C04FD655B5}

FixRecipientTrackStatusTime DWORD 1

I rebooted it after making this change, though the KB article does not indicate this is necessary.  I have no idea if this was required or not - the machine needed it outside of this change.

From:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938650

Comment: I know that you're answering your own question, but just links are not encouraged as answers. You should put the content that helped you in your answer and *then* provide the link.

Comment: Sure thing, done